# update ng-repeat item's data inside ng-repeat at click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I’m having my first steps with angularjs framework, and I’m not understanding how I can update my second ng-repeat data inside each of the first’s item ng-repeat only when a user click on it (lazy loading).

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="loadInvoices(customer); showDetails = !showDetails;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            </td>
            <td>{{customer.ClientId}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="showDetails">
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <tbody ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{invoice.Id}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr><!--showDetails-->
    </tbody><!--.customer-->
</table>
```

How can I achieve it? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: have you tried in you ng-repeat to change `ng-repeat="invoice in invoices"` by `ng-repeat="invoice in customer.invoices"`

Comment: Hi @JonathandeM. , thank you for your answer. My customer don't have invoices property at that point, I only will get it (lazy loading) when the user click at button: $scope.loadInvoices = function (customer) {
        //http request
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<button ng-click="loadInvoices(customer);" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn- xs">Invoces</button>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.loadInvoices = function(customer) {
    if (this.showDetails = !this.showDetails) {
        if (!this.invoices) {
            // Load invoices for current customer (probably using service)
            Customer.loadInvoices(customer.ClientId).then(function(invoices) {
                customer.invoices = invoices;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

By checking `if (!this.invoices) {...}` (`this` points to the current customer scope) you make sure that current customer doesn't have loaded invoices yet and you need to load them. On subsequent button clicks `customer.invoices` is going to be already available and you will not load data again.

I also added an example how using `Customer` service would fit into this workflow.

#### View demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LerBd9ZTPLwhp8JZ6xwU?p=preview

Comment: The `this` inside promise success callback won't be the right context.

Answer (score 1):

**With the ng-controller directive**

Simply use the ng-controller directive to tell that a customer scope will be managed by an instance of the controller you pass in.

**With a custom directive**

Typical design for this: a customer directive with a customer controller which manages the scope of one customer.

The keys are:

- ng-repeat creates child scopes
- add a directive to attach a controller to each of those scopes
- you can now manage each customer scope independently.

**The controller, in both cases**

This controller will hold `loadInvoices` which will attach the `invoices` array to the customer scope.

> Why a custom directive ? You will also be able to have a separate template for a     customer, specific pre link and post link functions, etc.
>
> Why a customer specific controller since scope inheritance will enable the `loadInvoices` context to be the customer specific scope ? Extensibility, testability, decoupling.